# How to get a sha256 hash of a file using ANSI C

Tags: c, hash

Simply what the topic states, what's a memory efficient way to compute a sha256 hash of a file that's variable in size? I'm also willing to compromise using more memory for faster computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or use the OpenSSL libcrypto:

https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Message_Digests

Comment: (+1) but libssl takes some getting used to, the documentation is not easy to get into

Comment: +1 OpenSSL is FIPS-certified.  It may take some effort to learn to use it, but far *less* effort than coding a correct SHA-256 implementation.

Comment: There is a complete example at http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_DigestInit.html. You can replace the line  md = EVP_get_digestbyname(argv[1]); with md = EVP_sha256();

Comment: This link points to a 404. It should be updated and the important information should be covered in the answer itself.

Comment: Updated broken URL

Answer (score 6):

I used a simple stand-alone implementation by Christophe Devine -- and while his site seems to be off the Net, Google Code Search finds it
[in this place](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/digest/blob/master/src/sha256.c).

Using these `sha256.c` and `sha256.h`, the core of his `main()` function is simply

```
if( ! ( f = fopen( argv[1], "rb" ) ) )
        {
            perror( "fopen" );
            return( 1 );
        }

        sha256_starts( &ctx );

        while( ( i = fread( buf, 1, sizeof( buf ), f ) ) > 0 )
        {
            sha256_update( &ctx, buf, i );
        }

        sha256_finish( &ctx, sha256sum );

        for( j = 0; j < 32; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%02x", sha256sum[j] );
        }

        printf( "  %s\n", argv[1] );
}
```

The rest of the `main()` function validates the FIPS-180-2 test vectors, so you get that warm and fuzzy feeling too/ ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Con Kolivas's implementation](https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer/blob/master/sha2.c#L93) used in multi-threaded multi-pool FPGA and ASIC miner for bitcoin or well profiled [Dr Brian Gladman's code](http://brg.a2hosted.com//oldsite/cryptography_technology/sha/index.php).